# Decoding i386 opcodes to instructions

Tags: assembly, decode, opcodes

I'm trying to Is there any good resource available to learn **'decoding'** of i386 opcodes? Most of the websites talk about how to encode instructions, but I don't find anywhere something telling as to how to decode opcodes to instructions.

I've looked at the source code of some disassemblers, but I want some documentation as to how to decode opcodes to instructions.

Thanks and Regards,
Hrishikesh Murali

Comment: Read http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Answer (score 2):

Read the processor manuals, they have it described, though maybe not in complete details:

1. [Intel Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), in particular see Chapter 2 in Volume 2A and Appendix A in Volume 2B.
2. [AMD Manuals](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/pages/default.aspx), see Programmer's Manual Volume 3.

See also [How to interpret the opcode manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019843/how-to-interpret-the-opcode-manually)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to lean at a more programmatic level, olly's old [disasm engine](http://www.ollydbg.de/disasm.zip) is a very simple disassembler to learn from (written in C), and if you want to cover the more recent opcodes (and hidden/aliased opcodes), [bea-engine](http://www.beaengine.org/) is a great open-source disassem engine.